# Paginacion con procedimiento almacenado y consulta dinamica C# Net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, net

Que tal tengo que paginar el resultado de un procedimiento almacenado en  c# y la verdad quiero consultar con los expertos cual seria la mejor forma.

el procedimiento almacenado es el siguiente.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp.MtoProcedimiento.Listar]

 @ListEjercicios as varchar(MAX),
 @ListProcedimientos as VARCHAR(MAX),    
 @ListTipoEventos as VARCHAR(MAX),
 @ListTipoCaracteres as VARCHAR(MAX),
 @ListTipoCompras as VARCHAR(MAX)
 AS
  BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
     
SET @Query=N'select 
 MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId,
 MtoCompania.DescripcionCorta,
 MtoProcedimiento.Ejercicio,
 MtoProcedimiento.NoLicitacion,
 MtoProcedimiento.Descripcion,
 MtoEstado.MtoEstadoId,
 MtoEstado. Descripcion [Status],
 VistaProcedimientosIMS.numeroIM,
 MtoProcedimiento.CompraCovid [CompraCovid],
 ''Art.'' + MtoArticulo.Descripcion + '' Fracc. '' + DetalleArticulo.Descripcion as Fundamento,
 MtoProcedimiento.MtoTipoEventoId,
 MtoTipoEvento.DescripcionCorta [TipoEvento],
 MtoProcedimiento.MtoTipoCompraId,
 MtoTipoCompra.Descripcion [TipoCompra],
 MtoProcedimiento.MtoCaracterId,
 MtoCaracter.DescripcionCorta [TipoCaracter],
 (select Count(MtoContratoId) from MtoContrato where MtoContrato.EstadoContrato<>4 and      MtoContrato.MtoProcedimientoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoprocedimientoId) as NumContratos,
 (select sum(CantOrig * PrecioNeto) from VistaContratos
group by MtoProcedimientoId
having VistaContratos.MtoProcedimientoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId) as MontoOriginal
 from MtoProcedimiento
 left join MtoTipoCompra on MtoTipoCompra.MtoTipoCompraId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoTipoCompraId
 left join MtoEstado on MtoEstado.MtoEstadoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoEstadoId
 left join MtoInvestigacionOcupa on      MtoInvestigacionOcupa.MtoProcedimientoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId
 left join MtoInvesMercado on       MtoInvesMercado.MtoInvesMercadoId=MtoInvestigacionOcupa.MtoInvesMercadoId
 LEFT join VistaProcedimientosIMS ON      VistaProcedimientosIMS.MtoProcedimientoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId
 left join MtoArticulo on MtoArticulo.MtoArticuloId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoArticuloId
 left join DetalleArticulo on      DetalleArticulo.DetalleArticuloId=MtoProcedimiento.DetalleArticuloId
 left join MtoCompania on MtoCompania.MtoCompaniaId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoCompaniaId
 left join MtoTipoEvento on MtoTipoEvento.MtoTipoEventoId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoTipoEventoId
 left join MtoCaracter on MtoCaracter.MtoCaracterId=MtoProcedimiento.MtoCaracterId
 where MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId>0 
 ';
    
 IF @ListEjercicios!=0
  BEGIN 
   SET @Query = @Query + ' AND MtoProcedimiento.Ejercicio in (' + @ListEjercicios +')'
 END


 IF @ListProcedimientos IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN 
   
   SET @Query= @Query + ' AND MtoProcedimiento.MtoProcedimientoId in (' + @ListProcedimientos +')'    
  END 

    IF @ListTipoEventos IS NOT NULL 
       BEGIN 
        SET @Query = @Query + ' AND MtoTipoEvento.MtoTipoEventoId in (' + @ListTipoEventos +')'
       END 


 IF @ListTipoCaracteres IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN 
   SET @Query = @Query + ' AND MtoCaracter.MtoCaracterId  in (' + @ListTipoCaracteres +')'  
  END 

 IF @ListTipoCompras IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN 
   SET @Query = @Query + ' AND MtoTipoCompra.MtoTipoCompraId  in (' + @ListTipoCompras +')' 
  END 
 

PRINT @Query 


 EXECUTE sp_executesql  @Query 

 END
```

al inicio cuando la información era poca no tenia problemas pero ahora la base de datos se ha incrementado y necesito realizar la paginación.

agradecere todo el apoyo.

Comment: Dudo mucho (o muchísimo) que una consulta dinámica de esa complejidad, te funcione más rápido, (y además porque parece enlazar con vistas que tendrán otras tantas tablas) aunque esté paginada, porque va a tener que hacer el motor de todo, cada vez que obtenga la query.  Puedes buscar paginados con `TOP`, con `OFFSET FETCH` o con `RowNumber`. Probablemente top obtenga un pelín de mejor rendimiento, pero eso es algo basado en opinones, sin fundamento, con la información que ofreces. Esta pregunta solo se puede responder basándose en opiniones.

Comment: Tu código está abierto brutalmente a inyección de SQL. Te recomiendo que conviertas esas cadenas de texto en tablas antes de unirlas a código dinámico. Tengo que crear una respuesta que revise todos los problemas de la consulta.

Comment: Amigo luis cazares podrías indica algún ejemplo de como convertirlo a tablas.  gracias